# Get selectedItem in ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemspaneltemplate

I have the following code which posts buttons in rows and columns.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
<!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<!-- ItemTemplate -->
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="{Binding }" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my collection which populates the user controls

```cs
private Collection<TemplateView> _myCollection; 
public Collection<TemplateView> MyCollection
{ 
    get { return _myCollection; } 
    set { _myCollection = value; } 
}
```

How do I know which particular button is pressed? (row/column would suffice).
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you want to know, which `Button` was pressed? What does the underlying structure (`MyCollection`) look like?

Comment: MyCollection is a Collection of UserControls (TemplateView in my case)

`private Collection<TemplateView> _myCollection;
        public Collection<TemplateView> MyCollection{ get { return _myCollection; } set { _myCollection = value; } }`

Comment: You should put this code in your question. Well I can only think of an approach, which is not compatible to yours.

Comment: why not use ListBox instead of ItemsControl that way you will get the SelectionChanged Event or bind to the selected Item

Comment: btw if you don't put the @username of the person you want to get alert of the comment for example DHN doesn't know about you approach question unless he is checking this post periodicaly